# Error creating Key Pair: You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an EC2 instance and on the last step of launching I try to create a key pair ( which will generate a .pem file for login) and I get the below error.
Error
**Error creating Key Pair: You are not authorized to perform this operation.**

Can anyone tell me what authentication should I give to  my IAM right now I have Admin access.

Not very sure what is causing the Issue.

-Rashmi

Answer (score 3):

Try adding <del>AmazonEC2FullAccess</del> **CreateKeyPair** policy.

If you are not sure how to do it:

Log in to IAM, then choose necessary user and on *Permissions* tab click *Add permission* button. On next page click on *Attach existing policies directly* button and look for **CreateKeyPair** policy. Attach it. This worked for me.

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved.. we must have key and admin access for the profile IAM

Comment: Don't give full admin access to EC2, just add what you need. "ec2:CreateKeyPair"

Comment: at the time of answer I am not sure such policy existed. I searched a lot but couldn't find exact solution. But yes, now better would be user CreateKeyPair.

Comment: @Serge this is not actually a policy, but an action inside a policy document. See here for an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes Giving **AmazonEC2FullAccess** to the IAM user group solved the issue.

[image]

Above screen shows that when you create the group you are supposed to give access to the service.

Comment: Don't give full admin access to EC2, just add the permission you need

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to grant access only to required resources, not to all of them.
To create key pair it is enough to grant `EC2:CreateKeyPair` permission.

Comment: I'd try with ec2:ImportKeyPair permission instead. But definitely, I agree that it is a good practice to grant access to the required resources only, not full access.

Comment: This is a better answer. You could add details on how to add only the permission "EC2:CreateKeyPair" maybe.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to grant access only to the required resources.

And it's the best to  generate your own ssh keypair (ssh-keygen) and then import the public key into AWS, the required IAM permission required is `ec2:ImportKeyPair`.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1472323724000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:ImportKeyPair"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Reference](https://%20generate%20their%20own%20ssh%20keypair%20(ssh-keygen)%20and%20then%20import%20the%20public%20key%20into%20the%20AWS%20consol)